# Kendo UI TreeView Nodes lose custom assigned HtmlAttributes after Drag & Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I've assigned an ID attribute to each of my tree nodes to keep a hold of information I need on the controller so that I can save a modified Hierarchy.

However, when I drop a node, the Id attribute is removed.  I'm not sure if this is a bug, if I'm doing something wrong, or this is working as intended by the developers.

I've attached a screenshot of my alert window (code below), and two shots of the Html generated from Firebug.  One is before the Drop and one is from after.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
.Name("CompanyHierarchy")
.Events(events => events
    .DragEnd("HierarchyDragEnd")
)
.BindTo(Model.Hierarchy as System.Collections.IEnumerable, mappings =>
{
    mappings.For<Models.EnterpriseChildModel>(binding => binding
        .Children(c => c.Children)
        .ItemDataBound((item, c) =>
        {
            item.Text = c.Name;
            item.HtmlAttributes.Add("Id", c.EnterpriseID.ToString());
        })
    );
})
.DragAndDrop(true))
```

[image: Alert Window missing ID]
[image: Firebug showing ID on Html BEFORE Drop]
[image: Firebug showing lack of ID in Html AFTER Drop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution.  It was provided on the Kendo forums by a Telerik team member.  I'll post my altered code below as well:

> The HtmlAttributes are not persisted after drag&drop operations. In this particular case, it is best to add the Id to the item and access it through the dataItem method on the client.

Revised code:

**Add ID to dataItem:**

```
    @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("CompanyHierarchy")
    .Events(events => events
        .DragEnd("HierarchyDragEnd")
    )
    .BindTo(Model.Hierarchy as System.Collections.IEnumerable, mappings =>
    {
        mappings.For<Models.EnterpriseChildModel>(binding => binding
            .Children(c => c.Children)
            .ItemDataBound((item, c) =>
            {
                item.Text = c.Name;
                item.Id = c.EnterpriseID.ToString();
            })
        );
    })
    .DragAndDrop(true)
)
```

**Obtain the info from dataItem:**

```
        function HierarchyDragEnd(e) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var originDataItem = $("#CompanyHierarchy").data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.sourceNode);
            var originNodeId = originDataItem.id;
            var originNodeText = originDataItem.text;
            var destinationDataItem = $("#CompanyHierarchy").data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.destinationNode);
            var destinationNodeId = destinationDataItem.id;
            var destinationNodeText = destinationDataItem.text;

            var dropPosition = e.dropPosition;
        }, 100);
    }
```